# Help with zc.buildout script to install Satchmo

Tags: python, django, distribution, buildout, satchmo

Im trying to re-create a [this](http://www.satchmoproject.com/blog/2010/aug/01/satchmo-virtualenv/) satchmo environment using a buildout script:

```
[buildout]
parts = 
django
satchmo

eggs =
pycrypto
PIL
pyyaml
trml2pdf
sorl-thumbnail
django-registration
django-caching-app-plugins
django-threaded-multihost
django-signals-ahoy
django-keyedcache
django-livesettings
django
satchmo
Sphinx
docutils

extensions = 
mr.developer
buildout.eggtractor

auto-checkout =
django-caching-app-plugins
django-threaded-multihost
django-signals-ahoy
django-keyedcache
django-livesettings
satchmo

sources = sources

[sources]
django-caching-app-plugins = hg http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-caching-app-plugins/
django-signals-ahoy = hg http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-signals-ahoy/
django-threaded-multihost = hg https://bkroeze@bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-threaded-multihost/
django-keyedcache = hg http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-keyedcache/
django-livesettings = hg http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings/
satchmo = hg http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/

[trml2pdf]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
find-links = http://www.satchmoproject.com/snapshots/trml2pdf-1.2.tar.gz
eggs = trml2pdf

[satchmo]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
find-links = ./src/satchmo
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
version = 1.2.3
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

The buildout itself is running fine, my issue now is one of dependancy.

Everything satchmo needs is installed, but running clonesatchmo.py complains that PIL is not installed when I can see it clearly is, so im guessing I havent "told" buildout that satchmo relies on PIL.

Im still confused about what goes in the "eggs" section and what goes in the "parts" section, and when they need to go in both?

Can anyone see anything wrong here or advise on how to configure dependancies?

Thanks in advance,

James